# How to determine which values had a status change from the prior month SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the dataset in the image

105665 Status changed 03-2017, Decommissioned from the prior month of 02-2017, Pending Decommissioned.

On a monthly basis, I need to determine which Assets have changed Status from the "prior" month.  I was thinking a new field is needed that tells me which Assets have changed status from the prior month but don't know how to determine that logic.  I will also need a count of Assets of how many moved from Pending Decommissioned to Decommissioned for example or from Installed to Pending Decommissioned but I'll worry about that part later.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcfix.jpg)

(I have found similar cases but not exactly like this one so although I still tried those solutions, none of them worked for me).

Many thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  How did they fail?  What are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 0):

In your status table, you can join to the prior month, showing those rows that have a different value.  Below assumes your dates are not text.

```
Select tm.asset
     , tm.date
     , lm.date
     , tm.status
     , lm.status
from table tm
inner join table lm
   on tm.date = lm.date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   and tm.asset = lm.asset
```

Comment: Hello, All the data is within one table like the image attached.  I'll give this a go though..  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps add your query to your question.  Perhaps describe what "didn't work" means with any detail.  Perhaps provide sample of output that you would like to achieve.